# Conditionally Filling NaN Values When Merging Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with two shared columns (`Symbol`, `Date`) that I am trying to merge on:

`df1`

```
  Company Symbol   ID        Date  Price
0   A Inc     AA  123  2019-03-31    1.0
1   A Inc     AA  123  2019-06-30    NaN
2   A Inc     AA  123  2019-09-30    3.0
3   B Inc     BB  456  2019-03-31    5.0
4   B Inc     BB  456  2019-06-30    6.0
5   B Inc     BB  456  2019-09-30    7.0
6   X Inc     XX  999  2019-03-31    9.0
```

`df2`

```
  Symbol        Date  Price  Income
0     AA  2019-03-31    1.1      10
1     AA  2019-06-30    2.1      11
2     AA  2019-09-30    3.1      12
3     BB  2019-03-31    5.1      14
4     BB  2019-06-30    6.1      15
5     BB  2019-09-30    7.1      16
6     ZZ  2019-03-31    8.0      20
```

If `Price` exists in `df1` and `df2`, then I want to use the one from `df1`; however, in cases where it doesn't exist in `df1`, I want to use the one from `df2`, so that the output looks like:

```
 Company Symbol     ID        Date   Price  Income
0   A Inc     AA  123.0  2019-03-31    1.0    10.0
1   A Inc     AA  123.0  2019-06-30    2.1    11.0
2   A Inc     AA  123.0  2019-09-30    3.0    12.0
3   B Inc     BB  456.0  2019-03-31    5.0    14.0
4   B Inc     BB  456.0  2019-06-30    6.0    15.0
5   B Inc     BB  456.0  2019-09-30    7.0    16.0
6   X Inc     XX  999.0  2019-03-31    9.0     NaN
7     NaN     ZZ    NaN  2019-03-31    8.0    20.0
```

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Symbol'], how='outer')` gets me close, but how do I replace the `NaN` values in `Price_x` with the value in the `Price_y` column before dropping `Price_y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it after the `merge`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Symbol'], how='outer')
df3['Price']=df3.Price_x.fillna(df3.Price_y)
df3=df3.drop(['Price_x','Price_y'],axis=1)
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Price_y'`

Comment: @MSD but how do I replace the NaN values in Price_x with the value in the Price_y column b, you do not have price_y ?

Comment: When I do `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Symbol'], how='outer')`, there is a column for both `Price_x` and `Price_y`

Comment: @MSD update change the `df3.Price_x.fillna(df3.Price_y)`

Comment: There might be a typo in your answer. Should it be `df3['Price']=df3.Price_x.fillna(df3.Price_y)` instead one `df2`?